# Executing script requiring root access via CGI

Tags: python, apache, cgi, root, sudoers

I have a script **script.py** which I'm able to execute via CGI by navigating to *mydomain.com/runscript*.

The script however makes a subprocess call to **echo "mysqldump ..." | sudo -i** and **sudo python** using **os.system(COMMAND)**. When I attempt to run the script via the weblink, I get this error in */var/log/apache2/error.log*:

> [Fri Jul 29 16:52:42.515223 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 3013] [client ##.###.##.##:#####] AH01215: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

This is because CGI runs as user **www-data**, which doesn't have sudo permission.

I've tried adding this to my **sudoers** file:

```
%www-data    ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/scripts/script.py
```

however the errors persist. Why are the subprocess calls not receiving root access, and how can I give it to them and ONLY them? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the password into sudo command by piping it:

`echo <your password> | sudo -S <your command>`